# Please wait while the indexes are being refreshed” in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

We have **2200 products** in our **Magento 1.9** store. I am trying to add more products from CSV. After uploading CSV and running CSV file in the popup the following keep showing with loader,

> Please wait while the indexes are being refreshed.

Can anyone tell that why refreshing the indexes takes too much time? and How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Indexer process takes time in magento depends how much products in your store. It also depends on your server memory_limit and execution time. After import process, you can run indexing process manually from admin or run php script from the root of magento.

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
umask( 0 ); Mage :: app( "default" );
$indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {
    $process->reindexEverything();
}
?>
```

you can also try to truncate `´catalog_product_flat_%´` tables (`catalog_product_flat_1`, `catalog_product_flat_2`, `catalog_product_flat_3` etc.) in MySQL console or via phpMyAdmin:

```
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_1´; 
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_2´; 
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_3´;
```

and then make indexing. In this way you can make fast indexing process.

Answer (score 1):

They could be stuck, check var/lock and clear the lock files in there, then restart the indexing via shell to monitor it.

Comment: there is no lock directory in var. Secondly I have to reindexing manually each time after importing products?

Comment: If you are using update on save the indexers can trigger over and over during import.